# Writing iPhone apps with PhoneGap, Appcelerator etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova

I was dumbfounded today, when I read that Apple has allowed PhoneGap apps for quite some time now. How does PhoneGap work? Do all HTML5, CSS, and JS get converted into native Objective-C code? Or is it just a container with actual HTML code inside? Wouldn't that be a huge security risk?

Then again I'm wondering, if you can tell PhoneGap apps apart from XCode apps? If they run native code, I guess it should be as smoothly. So what are the limitations and how come not many people use it, or at least I haven't heard of many? After all Javascript is pretty powerful.

Comment: This doesn't really ask a direct question.

Comment: Well, yes. There are several questions involved. Difference in code, security features of not-native code, real native code or just a container...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap does not get converted to native code. Other [frameworks](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) take this route.

Your HTML/CSS/JS are wrapped in a native wrapper, depending on the platform. This makes it far easier to port you to different platforms, including iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Palm, and Symbian. In my experience this is not the end of your problems, [just a new set of problems](http://mobilehtml5.org/).

Comment: And to add to this answer, yes, users can tell when an app is not written in native code. There's a very limited set of tools available using PhoneGap or Appcelerator.

Comment: yes, it will look and feel like a web page. [JQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com) assisted with this.

Comment: @ MishieMoo Appcelerator is native UI, users cannot tell the difference

Comment: @AaronSaunders While Appcelerator is fairly extensive, and is probably OK for the 90% use case, there are certain things that will limit you, especially when it comes to optimizing performance.